Can a fine-grained (thin-layered) eutectic microstructure be formed entirely of solidifying sulfides?
The purpose of this question is mainly to get a better intuition based on examples, so feel free to post any relevant example. Selenide instead of sulfide is also interesting.
However, there will also be a practical application if all the following extra requirements are satisfied:

One of the sulfides is either bismuth or lead sulfide.
The solids are not ferromagnetic.
Volume fraction of the solid phases is nearly equal.
At least one of the solid phases is a semiconductor.


Searching on the ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database yields 48 ternary Bi-S-X entries and a similar number of Pb-S-X entries (some are the same ternary but different temperature/compositions). I'm not well versed in which binary or ternary phases are ferromagnetic or semiconductors to narrow things down to begin with. And then there is the whole kinetics question of just how to get a eutectic to solidify in your stated microstructure. This is just way too broad.

With my limited knowledge, I thought faster cooling rate always gives thinner layers. Also, perhaps adding an inert solid powder for better nucleation may help. Let's just read out the volume fraction from the phase diagram near the melting temperature. 100 or so diagrams is worth looking, but unfortunately ASM database refuses to function right now (I created an account).

The kinetics are hard because you have to get the temperature gradient just right so lateral segregation is sufficient to separate the two phases as the solidification front moves, yet the segregation is small enough that your layers end up thin. Recall that the layers are along the direction of solidification. Now, should you be able to grow alternate layers by something like atomic layer deposition or chemical vapor deposition that would be different.

Thanks for the insight. Actually, CVD and ALD are not suitable exactly because of this wrong direction of layer growth. I have thought about many kinds of alternatives already.

Oops, I just realized, ASM wants me to pay in order to see any diagram at all.  It's not cheap, so no hope for me to find something there. I wonder whether it's even legal for anyone who has access via institution to post information here, as an answer.

Do you have access to a university or other technical library (which is how I get access)? They may have reference books on phase diagrams, many published by ASM.  Details of specific systems can usually be traced back to journal articles, although access to them is also usually through libraries.

In my city, there is a library. Not technical, though. I'm not sure, whether you mean online or real libraries. I have never been involved in any university. I have a 9-year education, then some self-study.

Hmmmmm, that makes things more difficult. A town library would be unlikely to have technical reference material like phase diagram handbooks. However, Google will come up with a number of hits - some are paywalled, some are open access, and some are on, e.g., ResearchGate or other platforms. It does make thorough methodical searching more difficult. However, congratulations on coming up with a very interesting question that could be a very fun topic.
